# COBOL capture arrow keystrokes

Tags: input, console, cobol

I'm completely new to COBOL, so as a learning excercise (and just for the sake of it) I'm trying to make a small console based game of connect 4. However I'm struggling to find a way of listening for and reading in keystrokes (for example using the arrow keys to move a piece left and right) without having to press enter after. So far the best solution I've found is to use Microfocus' Enhanced Accept/Display (Adis) which allows the use of the function keys in the manner I would like. I was wondering if there was something I may have missed, or a way of using Adis that would permit me the same sort of functionality with other keys than the function keys. The following program (shamelessly copied from https://www.microfocus.co.jp/manuals/SE/books/uisckb.htm) demonstrates the use of the function keys in the manner I would like:

```
 1$set noosvs mf ans85
 2**********************************************************
 3* Copyright Micro Focus International 2000. All Rights   *
 4* Reserved. This demonstration program is provided for   *
 5* use by users of Micro Focus products and may be used,  *
 6* modified and distributed as part of your application   *
 8* provided that you properly acknowledge the copyright   *
 9* of Micro Focus in this material.                       *
 9**********************************************************
10
11**********************************************************
12*                                                        *
13*                        FUNKEY.CBL                      *
14*                                                        *
15*    This program demonstrates how to decode function    *
16*    keys using the x"af" call.                          *
17*                                                        *
18**********************************************************
19 special-names.
20     crt status is key-status.
21
22 working-storage section.
23 01 flag                        pic 9(2) comp-x value 1.
24 01 user-key-control.
25     05 enable-fn-keys          pic 9(2) comp-x value 1.
26     05 filler                  pic x         value "1".
27     05 first-user-key          pic 9(2) comp-x value 1.
28     05 number-of-keys          pic 9(2) comp-x value 10.
29
30 01 key-status.
31     05 key-type                pic x.
32     05 key-code-1              pic 9(2) comp-x.
33     05 filler                  pic x.
34 01 any-data                    pic x.
35 01 key-code-1-display          pic z9.
36
37 procedure division.
38     perform enable-keys
39     perform accept-function-key
40     perform tell-which-key-was-pressed
41     perform stop-run.
42
43 enable-keys.
44     call x"af" using flag user-key-control.
45
46 accept-function-key.
47     display spaces upon crt
48     display "Press a function key: F1 to F10" at 0505
49     accept any-data at 0540.
50       
51 tell-which-key-was-pressed.
52     evaluate key-type
53      when 0 display "You pressed <Enter>" at 0705
54      when 1
55         move key-code-1 to key-code-1-display
56         display "You pressed function key" at 0705
57         display key-code-1-display         at 0730
58     end-evaluate.
59
60 stop-run.
61     stop run.
```

Comment: It would be more useful to (also) post your own code, which doesn't demonstrate the use of function keys the way you would like, so people who are reading this may help you to fix your code.

Answer (score 1):

It you are up for using a little non-conventional COBOL, the S-Lang library is the bee's knees when it comes to keyboard handling.  No ADIS required, but with care the two can live peacefully together.  Trying this example will require GNU Cobol 1.1 and libslang (by John E. Davis, jedsoft).

```
OCOBOL >>SOURCE FORMAT IS FIXED
      *> ***************************************************************
      *> Date:      20090503
      *> License:   Copyright 2009, Brian Tiffin
      *>            licensed for use under the GNU GPLv2
      *> Purpose:   Experimental S-Lang keyboard interface
      *> Tectonics: cobc -x slangkey.cob -lslang
      *> ***************************************************************
       identification division.
       program-id. slangkey.

       data division.
       working-storage section.
       01 thekey               usage binary-long unsigned.
       01 thekm                usage binary-long.
       01 result               usage binary-long.

      *> exit handler address and priority (prio is IGNORED with OC1.1)
       01 install-flag       pic 9 comp-x value 0.
       01  install-params.
           02 exit-addr      usage is procedure-pointer.
           02 handler-prio   pic 999 comp-x.

      *> ***************************************************************
       procedure division.

      *> Initialize low and high level S-Lang terminal routines
       call "SLtt_get_terminfo" end-call
       call "SLkp_init" returning result end-call
       if result equal -1
           display "problem intializing S-Lang tty" end-display
           stop run giving 1
       end-if

       call "SLang_init_tty" using
           by value -1     *> abort char
           by value -1     *> flow ctrl
           by value 0      *> output processing
         returning result
       end-call
       if result equal -1
           display "problem intializing S-Lang tty" end-display
           stop run giving 1
       else
           display "Keyboard in special mode" x"0d" end-display
       end-if

      *> install an exit handler to put terminal back
       set exit-addr to entry "tty-reset"
       call "CBL_EXIT_PROC" using
           install-flag
           install-params
           returning result
       end-call
       if result not equal zero
           display "error installing exit procedure" end-display
       end-if

      *> Not sure?  Have SLang handle ^C or let GNU Cobol take over?
       call "SLang_set_abort_signal" using by value 0 end-call

      *> The demo.  Fetch a key, then fetch a keycode.  4 times.
      *>   SLang terminals display newline as newline.  Need explicit
      *>   CR to get a carriage return.  Hence the x"0d".
      *>   Plus, output is buffered until line terminators.
       display
           "Tap a normal key, then tap a 'special' key, ie F1, 4 times"
           x"0d"
       end-display
       perform 4 times
           call "SLang_getkey" returning thekey end-call
           display thekey space with no advancing end-display
           call "SLkp_getkey" returning thekm end-call
           display thekm x"0d" end-display
       end-perform

      *> Exit handler will take care of resetting terminal
       goback.


      *> ***************************************************************
      *> Exit procedure to ensure terminal properly reset
      *> ***************************************************************
       entry "tty-reset".
       call "SLang_reset_tty" end-call
       display "exit proc reset the tty" end-display
       goback.

       end program slangkey.
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party but:

Documentation for ADIS can be found at https://supportline.microfocus.com/Documentation/books/sx51/sx51indx.htm - look for "Character user interfaces", and specifically the section "Keyboard handling via ADIS". The paragraph "enable-function-keys" in your code enables the function keys from F1 to F10. What you need to do is change the function of the cursor keys, which are ADIS keys, and to do this you need

```
01 adis-key-control.
   05 enable-adis-keys        pic 9(2) comp-x value 1.
   05 filler                  pic x         value "2".
   05 first-adis-key          pic 9(2) comp-x value 3.
   05 number-of-adis-keys     pic 9(2) comp-x value 8.
```

Then add the line

```
call x"af" using flag adis-key-control.
```

to the paragraph enable-function-keys. This will allow you to capture cursor left, right, up, and down, plus Home, tab, backtab, and End.

Comment: Late answers that add value are welcomed on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I do not  have Micro Focus COBOL, but a quick internet search seems to indicate that the example you chose introduces some confusion by using the term `function-keys` and show values received from pressing `function-keys`.

It may be that using the function-keys was the simplest for the example, because the key-value is 1 to 10, so needing no translation from key-value to key that you understand. It shows 3, you know it means F3.

The only clue in the example you show is `05 number-of-keys          pic 9(2) comp-x val`. If the number of keys used by the x'af' CALL is configurable, then it can changed, then, likely, keys themselves can be changed.

You ask about ADIS (Micro Focus's `Extended ACCEPT and DISPLAY`)? Yes. It is all within ADIS. All the cursor keys are part of the `Standard Adis Key Functions`.

If you run the example program and press the arrow keys instead of a function key, what happens?

I searched for `micro focus user interface manual` and found enough information to make it necessary to know which particular Micro Focus product you have.